# Is there a way to get all the permutations of $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, determinant

I need to calculate the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix by "direct computation", so I thought that means using the formula

$$\sum_{\sigma \in S_4} (-1)^{\sigma}a_{1\sigma(1)}\ldots a_{n\sigma(n)}$$

So first I wanted to write down all the permutations of $S_4$ but I've only got 23 out of the 24 and I can't think of the last one. I was wondering if there is a "method" I can use to get all of them (apart from Googling them) and make sure that they are all unique and I've not done the same one twice?

Right now, I have

$$\begin{matrix} () & (34) & (143) & (1243) \\ (12) & (123) & (234) & (3241)\\  (13) & (132) & (243) & (1324) \\ (14) & (124) & (324) & (4231) \\ (23) & (142) & (1234) & (4321) \\ (24) & (134) & (2134) \\ \end{matrix}$$

What one am I missing?

Comment: Expanding the determinant along a row is a direct computation.

Comment: By the way, you have repetitions in your list, $(3241)$ is same as $(1324)$. Missing $(12)(34)$ and its relatives.

Comment: Note that $\,(243)=(324)\,$ and you're missing the three involutions of the form $\,(ab)(cd)\,$ ,with all $\,a,b,c,d,\,$ different.

Comment: You could avoid repetition if you **always** write cycles beginning with the smallest integer, for example $\,(324)=(243)\,$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the cycle structure is particularly helpful for *enumerating* all permutations. There it is easier to think of a permutation as simply the numbers form 1 to 4 arranged in some order.

All such sequences can be generated systematically by taking first those that have 1, then those that have 2 in the first place, and so on. Within each group, do a similar split on the second place, and proceed recursively. You get:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,4,3
1,3,2,4
1,3,4,2
1,4,2,3
1,4,3,2
2,1,3,4
...
2,4,3,1
3,1,2,4
...
4,3,1,2
4,3,2,1
```

If you use this enumeration to compute determinants, you may notice that it you add the terms in the order (terms from permutations with 1 in the first place) + (terms from permutations with 2 in the first place) + ... + (terms from permutations with 4 in the first place), what you're doing is exactly expansion by minors!

Comment: If I'm working out the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix like, then is my second term * matrix of $(2 \times 2)$ minor going to be negative?

Comment: Yes, the signs will work out correctly. In the 4×4 example, the "234" subdeterminant appears with a positive sign, but the "134" and "123" subdeterminants are negative because the permutations that take the initial "1234" to "2134" and "4123" are _odd_. On the other hand, "1234" to "3124" is an _even_ permutation, so the "124" subdeterminant appears with positive sign.

Comment: @Kaish: Why don't you use GAP? This question can be easily proved by that.

Comment: @BabakSorouh Whats GAP?

Comment: @Kaish: It is a powerful software in group theory.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have repeating permutations. For example: $(243)=(324)$ (the same with the four-cycles... there should only be 6 of them).
You are missing the permutations of the structure $(--)(--)$. For example $(12)(34)$,$(13)(24)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the permutations of $1,2,3,4$ and then put each one of them in cycle notation. For example here are all the permutations of $1,2,3,4$

$[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 2, 3],
[1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1],
[2, 4, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 4, 2], [3, 2, 1, 4],
[3, 2, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 3, 2],
[4, 2, 1, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [4, 3, 1, 2], [4, 3, 2, 1]]$

For example $[3,1,2,4]$ from above in cylce notation is $(132)$. Put in a columns 
so you have for each

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3&4 \\ 3 & 1 & 2&4\end{pmatrix} $

So you can see $1$ goes to $3$; $3$ goes to $2$; $2$ goes to $1$ and $4$ is fixed.

$[3,4,2,1]$ is $(1324)$ in cycle notation as follows

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3&4 \\ 3 & 4 & 2&1\end{pmatrix} $

$1$ goes to $3$; $3$ goes to $2$; $2$ goes to $4$; and $4$ goes to $1$

Alternatively you can go to [Sagemath](http://sagemath.org/) sign up for the online version if you are not signed up already and run

```
    sage: S4=SymmetricGroup(4)
    sage: S4.list()
```

to get

$[(), (3,4), (2,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3), (2,4), (1,2), (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3),
(1,2,3,4), (1,2,4,3), (1,2,4), (1,3,2), (1,3,4,2), (1,3), (1,3,4),
(1,3)(2,4), (1,3,2,4), (1,4,3,2), (1,4,2), (1,4,3), (1,4), (1,4,2,3),
(1,4)(2,3)]$